# How to make <ul> list like this?

Tags: css, xhtml

I'm new web Designer and making a site, which has list like this

See this image <strike>( i can't add image in question, bcoz i need 10 rep)</strike>

http://shup.com/Shup/379626/11068201228-My-Desktop.png

[alt text http://stashbox.org/947532/11068201228-My-Desktop.png](http://stashbox.org/947532/11068201228-My-Desktop.png)

How to make list like this if i want to keep one `<ul>` Is it possible?

Comment: I think you can get 10 rep by filling your profile

Comment: just give this man some rep...to get him started

Comment: @rabidmachine9 - Thanks but I'm a Woman. :)

Answer (score 5):

It is possible by floating all your li elements, and setting the width of your ul and li elements. The display order will be
1 2
3 4
5 6
if you use this method.

Comment: Why? Because numbers length can vary I guess?

Comment: the problem in image list items has same name but after completion name of list item can be varied. in char. lenth.

Comment: It's not "ideal" for a ul either. Even though "ul" means unordered, in many cases people expect some kind of order ( usually alphabetical or by date ). I know people should use an ol in this case, but such is life.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the simplest CSS you can use to accomplish what greg0ire is talking about:

```
<ul class='myList'>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>

.myList { width : 300px; }
.myList li { float: left; width: 150px; }
```

Of course, as mentioned this will not create a newspaper-column-like format. IT will float left to right before popping down.

For multi-column formats, you'd have to either use a device which supports CSS3 or use javascript.

In newer versions of Firefox, CSS like this may work:

```
.myList{
  -moz-column-count:3;
}
```

Comment: in your first solution . my `li` item's will not be fixed they can be changed. some will have less character some will more. not all item will have Business Organization always. It's just a Mock-up. so what will happen if i will give fixed width to `li`?

Comment: It really depends. If your overall layout is fixed and not fluid, then chances are you have a finite space for your columns anyhow. A fixed width will cause wrapping if it pushes past the end. You'll probably want to clear the float of every "odd-numbered" item. If you're using a fluid layout, you can use percentages or `em` units if you want the sizing to reflect the font-size. NOTE: IF YOU DON'T set a width, you won't have the appearance of columns.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out to do multi-column lists:
http://www.alistapart.com/articles/multicolumnlists/

For the custom bullets, specific style property you need to modify is:

```
list-style-image: url(someimage.gif);
```

Check out this link for more detailed info:
http://www.alistapart.com/articles/taminglists/

find the section called "Markers".